# The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous' on wsDualHttpBinding

Tags: wcf, app-config, wsdualhttpbinding, transport-security

I have a client-server application. My server site is on IIS.
My client App.config is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsDualHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSDualHttpBinding_IService" />
            </wsDualHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8083/Service.svc"                  
                      binding="wsDualHttpBinding"
                      bindingConfiguration="WSDualHttpBinding_IService"    
                      contract="ServiceReference.IService"
                      name="WSDualHttpBinding_IService">
            </endpoint>
        </client>
   </system.serviceModel>
```

When I press a button on my application - I get the following error:
**The http request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'anonymous'.**
It seems like in order to resolve this problem I have to use the following code:

```
<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
  <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
  <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
</security>
```

However, what should I do since wsDualHttpBinding doesn't support transport security?
Maybe is there any declaration on IIS itself?

Comment: Hi Tali B, is this problem fixed?, because I am also facing same problem 'HTTP request was forbidden' but it is not the case that always I am getting this error. But not sure whether issue is because security mode is not set to 'None'.